# Question about javascript event handler syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question appears to have been deleted yesterday before it could be answered, so I'm starting a new thread on the subject.

I've been trying to find cross-browser resize javascript, and ran across this syntax in one answer posted here:

```
$(window).resize(function()
```

I'm afraid I don't understand the syntax `$(window).`.  Is that something specific to jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You added your question as an answer to an old question.  This is the right way to do it!

`$(window)` is jQuery syntax for creating a jQuery object that contains the `window` object.  Certain events are triggered on this, for instance `resize`, `load`, etc.

This syntax adds a `resize` handler to the `window`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down `$(window).resize(function() { });`:

- `$` (an alias for `jQuery`) is simply the name of a JavaScript function.  In this case, it's the [jQuery object constructor function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/).
- `(window)` - since we're calling a function, parameters are enclosed in parentheses.  The `jQuery` function takes a number of parameters (selector strings, DOM element[s], other jQuery objects, and HTML strings).  Here, we're passing the DOM [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window) object, since we know it fires the [`onresize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onresize) event that we want to bind to.
- `.` - the `jQuery()` function returns a `jQuery` object—which has [many](http://api.jquery.com/) methods and properties—and we use a period to access those methods.
- `resize()` is a [method of the `jQuery` object](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).  Depending on the arguments you pass to it, it either triggers the `resize` event (when you pass no arguments) or binds a new event handler to the event (when you pass a function reference, like we are here).  Bound event handler(s) are called each time the event is triggered by code or by the browser.
- `function() { }` is the syntax for an [anonymous function](http://helephant.com/2008/08/javascript-anonymous-functions/).  The code you would write inside the `{ }` gets executed each time the function is called.  In this case, the function is called when the `resize` event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is specific to jQuery. Which is cross browser and free to download. I would suggest using jQuery for this since it takes care of all the cross browser difficulties for you. The `$(window)` is shorthand for `jQuery(window)` which selects the browser window and any options, events, and anything else that is associated with it

Comment: Well it's not really specific to jQuery - the Prototype.js library also uses a global "$" identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The "$" character in JavaScript can be used freely in variable and function names.  Thus, jQuery uses the identifier "$" as an alias for the "jQuery" function.

You can do this yourself:

```
var my$variable = "hello world";
alert(my$variable);
```

Or

```
function my$function() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/